# Use LaTeX expressions inside a kable table in a Revealjs presentation

Tags: r, latex, kable, kableextra, quarto

Since Quarto released, I've been keen on using Revealjs slides in order to present data projects, a nice and very interactive format.

Just like in Rmarkdown, it is easy to use LaTeX expressions inside slides: `$for_inline_exp$`, `$$centered_displayed_exp$$`.

I never had issues using LaTeX expressions inside tables (thanks to kableExtra) which produces the following output (see colnames) :[image: Table_pdf]

However, I'm not sure if it is currently supported in Revealjs, but despite using `escape = FALSE`, the colnames displays as follow: `$cos^2 (F_1)$`

In order to avoid it, I prefer not to use LaTeX in Revealjs tables, which gives:

[image: Table]

So, to my question, does anyone know if there is a way to make use of LaTeX expressions inside kable in a Revealjs output?

Here's an example of some code:

### Dependencies

```r
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
```

### Random Dataframe

```r
x <- data.frame(cbind(rnorm(5, mean=50, sd=10),
                      rnorm(5, mean=50, sd=10),
                      rnorm(5, mean=50, sd=10)))

names(x) <- c("some text", "$Cont(F_1)$","$\\frac{1}{n^2}$")
```

### KABLE

```r
color_1 = ifelse(x[,1] > mean(x[,1]),
       "green","red")

x %>%
kable(booktabs = T ,escape = F, align = 'c') %>%
    kable_classic(full_width = F,
                  position = "center",font_size = 35) %>%
column_spec(2,color = color_1)
```

Comment: Hi, can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to share it, it has been updated above

Answer (score 1):

You can add `format = "markdown"` to your `kable()` function. Note that this however breaks your color coding. See [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/kable-table-with-links-showing-raw-markdown-code-in-quarto-file/143073/2) for an explanation why `kable` work differently in quarto compared to Rmarkdown.
[image]

**EDIT 1**:

You could use a combination of `format = "latex"` and the `[parse-latex](https://github.com/tarleb/parse-latex)` filter:

````
---
format: revealjs
filters:
  - parse-latex
---


```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(cbind(
  rnorm(5, mean = 50, sd = 10),
  rnorm(5, mean = 50, sd = 10),
  rnorm(5, mean = 50, sd = 10)
))

names(x) <- c("some text", "$Cont(F_1)$", "$\\frac{1}{n^2}$")
color_1 <- ifelse(x[, 1] > mean(x[, 1]),
  "green", "red"
)

x %>%
  kable(booktabs = T, escape = F, align = "c", digits = 2, format = "latex") %>%
  kable_classic(
    full_width = F,
    position = "center", font_size = 15
  ) %>%
  column_spec(2, color = color_1)
```
````

Comment: Thank you for the anwser, However, is there a way to reduce the size of the table still ? kable_styling() won't work because of the output.

Comment: You could try to bind two kables together, one with only the kable header (format: markdown) and one with the columns without column header including kable_Styling (format:html). But tbh, that's not a very elegant solution..

Comment: I made an edit.